# V.I. Arnold's high school problem

Tags: soft-question, mathematics-education

According to his interview to the Notices of the AMS, when Vladimir I. Arnold was 12 years old (in 1949) his teacher I.V. Morozkin, gave to his classroom (apparently 6th grade of a soviet primary school) the following question (see http://www.ams.org/notices/199704/arnold.pdf)

> *Two women started at sunrise and each walked at a constant velocity. One went from $A$ 
>   to $B$ and the other from $B$ to $A$.  They met at noon and, continuing with no stop, 
>   arrived respectively at $B$ at 4 p.m. and at $A$ at 9 p.m. At what time was the sunrise 
>   that day?*

My question is not how to solve this problem, but rather *How to solve this problem using what 12 year old kids know* (or knew during the soviet era).

Comment: This is off-topic for MathOverflow.  It would probably get a good reception at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think Soviet 12 year olds might have been taught about harmonic means, proportions, and work related problems, which is appropriate for the problem. Also, trial and error and common sense converge to a solution quickly.  Gerhard "Probably Could Solve At Ten" Paseman, 2013.12.30

Comment: @Adeel: Kids who participate in Soviet (now Russian) Olympiads have totally different preparation.

Comment: This isn't that hard. Take a look at the MathCounts Target Round problems http://mathcounts.org/sites/default/files/u49/2013_State_Target.pdf , aimed for 11-14 year olds working at an average of 3 minutes a problem. They're at a comparable level of difficulty. Obviously, most 12 year olds don't know how to set up a word problem leading to the quadratic formula and solve it, but it's well with in range of a smart 12 year old, and Russian schools were extensively tracked, so Arnold's class was probably mathy kids.

Comment: For the record, I do this in about 3-4 minutes as follows: Drew a picture. Let $x$ be the distance from A to the meeting point, let $y$ be the distance from the meeting point to $x$. The sunrise (in hours before noon) is at time $4x/y$ and also $9y/x$, so $4x^2=9y^2$, we get $x:y = 3:2$, so sunrise is at 6 before noon. I was probably twice as fast when I was training for math competitions.

Comment: Why was this titled "high school problem?"

Comment: @DouglasZare: Which do you think would be a more suitable title?

Comment: How about, "V. I. Arnold's 6th grade problem?" High school usually doesn't include 6th grade.

Comment: @DouglasZare: That definitely sounds suitable. Nevertheless, this question is about to close in MathOverFlow, and I was advised to move in to MathStackExchange, as a more suitable site.

Comment: I am substantially younger than Arnold, but in 6-th grade (12 y.o.) we had a rigorous geometry course. We knew what similar triangles are, proportions and also how to represent a uniform motion with a straight line. There was no notion of "high school". This was called "secondary school" 10 or 11 years of study from 7 to 17 or 18.

Comment: But I suppose only a good pupil, in a good school could solve this problem in few minutes.

Comment: Arnold says somewhere (I can give a reference if needed) that he didn't use algebra to solve the problem when we first heard it.

Comment: I'd have been shocked if Arnold could \emph{not} solve this at 12!

Comment: Let T be the time traveled before noon.  The diagram A------X---B shows that 9 is to T as T is to 4.  Children can guess 6 without formally solving.

Comment: @EricZaslow: Some children might guess, but not so many of them!

Comment: Posted at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/622775/18398, as requested.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't it conceivable that 12 year olds could solve simple quadratic equations with integer coefficients by inspection as my generation learned, especially when the numbers are arranged, as here, to give a simple whole number solution?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, they didn't know how to solve such equations in 6th grade.

Comment: But here it reduces to factoring 108 as a product of two integers whose sum is 24, surely well within reach of a 12 year old Arnold.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: The first part of the problem uses merhods that we learned in primary school (translating text into formula and manipulating the results with simple algebra) to get the equation $s^2-24s+108=0$.

Comment: This is certainly plausible... even for poor American kids c. 1964. :)

Comment: If you define $x = 12-s$, so $x$ is the number of hours between sunrise and noon, then the equation is simpler: $x/4= 9/x$.